# Disable auto expand of edittext when typing

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

My activity have: 1 youtubePlayerView, 1 edittext below.
My youtube video stop accidently when i type more than 4 lines in the edittext.
I think the reason is that the other layout over the youtubePlayer layout, so that the youtube video stop.

**This is the LogCat:** W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.view.View
Anyone has solution for editted expanding problem.

**This is link youtube video i had recorded on my phone to demo this error:**
  https://youtu.be/zE8vzmaT0-Q

**this is my xml for that activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="13"
tools:context=".StudyActivity">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtubeView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"></com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:background="#1d75a1"
    android:elevation="18dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1.5dp"
    android:weightSum="16">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btPreviousTrack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="#bdf6f9"
        android:src="@drawable/previous_track" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerSelectTrack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"></Spinner>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btNextTrack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="#bdf6f9"
        android:src="@drawable/next_track" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btCheck"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="8.5"
        android:background="#bdf6f9"
        android:src="@drawable/check_green_mark" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etAnswer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:background="#5abce6"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="type answer here"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:lines="5"
    android:maxLines="5"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="#8edaf1"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Comment: Try giving maxHeight to your editText which will avoid expanding your EditText after that given height.

Comment: thanks, but edittext still expand, nothing different

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem , add this code to your EditText

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: thank for your comment, but i use layout_weight to display layout_height, so that setting layout_weight to 1 show make edittext area so small

Answer (score 0):

thank for you guys help, 
i've solved this problem by using another way.

add below codes to onCreated() to resize all the view when the keyboard show up, so that the keyboard layout will not over the youtubePlayerView layout, then the video will not be stopped.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```